# Select PHP em tabelas com caracteres especiais

Tags: php, mysql, linux

Por algum motivo o DBA colocou "ç" em nome de tabelas do banco Mysql e agora nao consigo fazer select nessas tabelas apartir do php:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql="select * from Tbl_login";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

O select roda. Mas o:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql="select * from Tbl_OrdemServiço";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Não traz resultados...mas se eu rodar esse select no banco ele traz.

Entre os vários testes que fiz deu-me também este erro:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '�o' at line 1

alguem pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema parece ser a incompatibilidade entre os *charsets* da base e do código/cliente/arquivo.

Quando o OP exibe a mensagem de erro:

> have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near **'�o'** at line

isso mostra que a `ç` foi convertida de forma errada.

A solução foi definir o charset da conexão

```
 $conn->set_charset("utf8")
```

Comment: +1 Talvez tivesses razão, apesar poder ser má prática, algumas pessoas não trabalham com o que criam, trabalham com o que encontram. E resolver um problema, é sempre melhor que evita-lo _(de momento tenho os votos bloqueados)_.

Comment: @Edilson, tem banco que vc usa `[ ]` colchetes para escapar nomes com caracteres especiais.

Comment: Eu normalmente prefiro não usar nenhum tipo de caráter especial, gosto de nomes direitos e simples, são fáceis de memorizar, e fáceis de manusear.

Answer (score 0):

Para procurar por uma palavra exata e/ou que possa causar algum erro de sintaxe no sql use aspas simples ao redor da palavra, e em sua query você está colocando ponto e virgula dentro da query em;

```
$sql="select * from Tbl_OrdemServiço;";
                              _Aqui ^
```

Faça da seguinte

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Tbl_OrdemServiço`";
```

Comment: Isso não faz difrença nesse caso.